# Xamarin iOS real device debug ignores breakpoints

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

**My environment:**

- Microsoft Visual Studio Version 17.8.5
- Xcode 15.2
- Using iPhone 7 with iOS 15.7.8 as real device for debugging my app
- Xamarin.Apple SDK 17.8.0.157
- Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2578
- Windows 11 (this is where I run my Visual Studio)
- MacOS Version 14.3 (23D56)

**The problem:**

I'm debugging the iOS project from my Xamarin app.

While using a iOS simulator, everything works as expected. But since for my testing scenario is not reliable using simulator, I start using my real iPhone for the purpose.

Everything went as expected for weeks. But yesterday an error message popped up:
*The debugger may be unstable now. It is recommended that you save all files and exit*

Since then, all breakpoints are getting ignored while debugging on real device. After a few minutes debugging, visual studio hangs and the debugger unsable message shows again.

**What I tried:**

- Clean & Rebuild
- Restart Visual Studio, Mac and iPhone
- Delete Visual Studio iOS Cache (Local/Xamarin/iOS)
- Delete app from device and install it again
- Set iOS build linker behaviour to **don't link**

(Edited after @Guangyu Bai - MSFT answer)

- Set Properties>Build>Advanced>Debugging information to Portable. At this point, after receiving two "Application Terminated" I was able to debug. Even after switching back to Debugging information to Full it was still working. But Visual Studio was just hanging at some breakpoints and I ended up getting another "The debugger may be unstable now". Very inconsistent behaviour.

Nothing from above worked. I'm just stuck without being able to hit breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I edited my original post after I tried your answer. Sadly, debug still not working as expected

Comment: It is recommended that you can create a new issue on the GitHub and follow it up. It is the issue caused by the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the known issue about [Breakpoints not hit in Class Library Project Referenced by Xamarin.iOS Project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12261) on the GitHub.

Someone mentioned that switching IOS project AND class library to "portable" worked. (in properties>build>advanced>debug information for anyone who needs it). You can try this solution.

If you can not solve this issue, it is recommended you can report it as a new issue on the GitHub.